# How to calculate VIF in python 3.6 with scipy 1.0.0?

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to import

`from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor`

This is working fine upto Scipy 0.19.

But , with Python 3.6.3 ,it's failing due to unavailability of `ss` module in Scipy 1.0.0.

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in <module>()
     41 from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
     42 from scipy import stats
---> 43 from scipy.stats.stats import ss
     44 from scipy import optimize
     45 from scipy.stats import chi2

ImportError: cannot import name 'ss'
```

Can anyone please guide me how to do VIF analysis using Scipy1.0.0 ?

Comment: It wasn't throwing any error when i executed the same. I'm using `python                     3.6.4                h6538335_1  defaults`, using the latest anaconda.

Comment: Duplicate on Stack Exchange: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877227/how-to-calculate-vif-in-python-3-6-with-scipy-1-0-0/49089230#49089230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `ss` module is in `scipy.stats` not `scipy.stats.stats` as of [scipy 0.17](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ss.html#scipy.stats.ss). Also, it is deprecated, but you seem to have figured that out.

Second, in the current `linear_model.py` on [github](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py), the `ss` package is no longer imported:

```
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
from scipy import stats
from scipy import optimize
```

What version is your statsmodels? Sounds like you may need to update it.